# Ways to find out how soon the AWS session expires?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sts, aws-credentials

**Prerequisites**

I have a script that works with AWS but does not deal with credentials explicitly. It just calls AWS API, expecting the credentials to be there according to [default credentials provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html#default-credential-chain). In fact, the wrapper that calls this script obtains temporary credentials and passes them in environment variables (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`).

**Problem**

The wrapper usually reuses existing credentials, and only asks to re-authenticate explicitly when they are about to expire. So there is a possibility that it passes credentials that have a few minutes left to live, which may not be enough, as the script execution usually takes long time. Unfortunately, I don't have control over the wrapper, so I would like to make the script check how much time it has left before making a decision whether to start or abort early to prevent failure in mid-flight.

AWS doesn't seem provide a standard way to query "how much time I have before my current session expires?" If I had control over the wrapper, I would make it pass the expiry date in an environment variable as well. I was hoping that `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` is a sort of a JWT token, but unfortunately it is not, and does not seem to contain any timestamp in it.

Can anyone suggest any other ways around the given problem?

Comment: Are you using this on an EC2 instance?

Comment: Nope, it's outside of AWS infrastructure.

Comment: There's a simple way to get that data from an EC2 instance, but that won't work in your case. I found this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html when looking for the problem you mention. Could that help?

Comment: Did anyone get any of the answers to work? None of those work for me. I'm doing an over-optimization to improve my daily workflow, don't login if the session if valid, and need the expiry time.

Answer (score 4):

One liners/bash functions for [BSD `date`](https://man.openbsd.org/date) (tested in macOS).

Requires [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) and [AWS CLI v2](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

```bash
aws-expiry () {
  aws configure get x_security_token_expires --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} | xargs -I {} sh -c 'TZ="UTC" date -j -f "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" "+%s" $1 2>/dev/null' -- {} | xargs date -j -f "%s"
}
```

To get expiry of AWS [SSO session cache file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/sso-configure-profile-token.html) (only if using SSO).

Assumes `cli_timestamp_format` not configured for [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)

```bash
aws-sso-expiry () {
  aws configure get sso_start_url --profile ${AWS_PROFILE} | xargs -I {} grep -h {} ~/.aws/sso/cache/*.json | jq .expiresAt | xargs -I {} sh -c 'TZ="UTC" date -j -f "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" "+%s" $1 2>/dev/null' -- {} | xargs date -j -f "%s"
}
```

Examples demonstrating values output:

```bash
aws configure get x_security_token_expires --profile ${AWS_PROFILE}
2024-01-24T17:14:43+11:00

aws configure get sso_start_url --profile ${AWS_PROFILE}
https://d-xxxxxxx.awsapps.com/start
```

Comment: I don't know where is the first answer getting "AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION" from. But I am using AWS SSO and the second line definitely does the trick! Thanks @Efren

Comment: I only get blank responses from these commands

Comment: @Drew which command exactly? The functions above only define a bash function , to run them need to then call them. These are examples you can set in bashrc as helpers.

Comment: `aws configure get sso_start_url --profile ${AWS_PROFILE}` is blank. I login with sso so I expected something to come out of that command

Comment: It will only work if you define `AWS_PROFILE` variable matching one of your configured profile names for the sso login you mention @Drew, eg:
[profile myssoprof]

Then, do `export AWS_PROFILE="myssoprof"` before running the command.

Comment: @Efren, OP makes no mention of SSO and I'm not using it either so have the same problem as Drew.  Just have the key id, secret key and session token and want to know expiry.  I did put these values in a profile, and tried that.

Comment: @Keeely if not using SSO then don't use the second part of the answer, I only added for completion, the first part is for credentials that are not from SSO.

Comment: @Efren unfortunately for the first part, I get a blank response, like Drew.

Comment: Note that an env variable is used to define the CLI profile name: `AWS_PROFILE`, have you set and export that @Keeely?

Comment: I didn't bother with the variable, I just put the value in there.  I only executed the first command, not the pipelines.  Nothing comes out, but this isn't surprising because neither AWS support nor GPT 3.5 said there's any way to get this info.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question. I get blank results from `sso_start_url` and `x_security_token_expires` flavors of the `configure get` command.

Comment: Note this was tested with AWS CLI v2, if empty outputs it means incorrect AWS CLI configuration or version support. Note also SSO requires different configuration steps. If the outputs are blank it probably means even the aws cli commands don't even work as the profile is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

`IMPORTANT Update: now $AWS_CREDENTIAL_EXPIRATION replaces $AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION`

> TODO: amend the answer below based on the important update above!

**You probably need to check for the value of `$AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION`**

```
echo $AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION
```

It should be giving you the expiration using the **Zulu Time (Coordinated Universal Time)** like below

```
2022-05-17T20:20:40Z
```

**Then would need to compare the date on your system against it.**

> Instructions below work on macOS, for Linux you may have to modify the `date` function params

Let's check the current system time in Zulu Time:

```
date -u +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

this should give something like the example:

```
2022-05-17T20:21:14Z
```

To automate things you can create a bash function to add to your `~/.bashrc` or favorite terminal theme

```
aws_session_time_left() {
  zulu_time_now=$1

  aws_session_expiration_epoch="`date -j -u -f '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' $AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION '+%s'`"
  zulu_time_now_epoch="`date -j -u -f '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' $zulu_time_now '+%s'`"

  if [[ $zulu_time_now < $AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION ]]; then
    secs="`expr $aws_session_expiration_epoch - $zulu_time_now_epoch`"
    echo "+`printf '%dh:%02dm:%02ds\n' $((secs/3600)) $((secs%3600/60)) $((secs%60))`"
  else
    secs="`expr $zulu_time_now_epoch - $aws_session_expiration_epoch`"
    echo "-`printf '%dh:%02dm:%02ds\n' $((secs/3600)) $((secs%3600/60)) $((secs%60))`"
  fi
}
```

To consult the result of your function you can run:

```
aws_session_time_left "`date -u +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'`"
```

**When your session is still active** can give you something like:

```
+0h:56m:35s
```

**or** (when the session has expired) can give you how long since it expired:

```
-28h:13m:42s
```

***NOTE** the hours can be over 24h*

> BONUS: simplified standalone script version without parameters below

for example, you can also have as a standalone file `get-aws-session-time-left.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use to find out IF "aws session expiration" exist AND compare the current system time to IT
# These are the expected result types we want to have:
# - "no aws session found" (NOTE: this does not mean there is no aws session open in another terminal)
# - how long until the session expires (for example +0h:59m:45s)
# - how long since the session expired (for example -49h:41m:12s)
# NOTE: the hours do not reset at every 24 hours, we do not require to display the days
# IMPORTANT: the date function arguments work on macOS, for other OS types may need adapting

if [[ $AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION != '' ]]; then
  zulu_time_now="`date -u +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'`" # TODO: see important note above

  aws_session_expiration_epoch="`date -j -u -f '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' $AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION '+%s'`" # TODO: see important note above
  zulu_time_now_epoch="`date -j -u -f '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' $zulu_time_now '+%s'`"                   # TODO: see important note above

  if [[ $zulu_time_now < $AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION ]]; then
    secs="`expr $aws_session_expiration_epoch - $zulu_time_now_epoch`"
    echo "+`printf '%dh:%02dm:%02ds\n' $((secs/3600)) $((secs%3600/60)) $((secs%60))`"
  else
    secs="`expr $zulu_time_now_epoch - $aws_session_expiration_epoch`"
    echo "-`printf '%dh:%02dm:%02ds\n' $((secs/3600)) $((secs%3600/60)) $((secs%60))`"
  fi
else
  echo "no aws session found"
fi
```

Then to consult the AWS session expiration, you can just run:

```
bash get-aws-session-time-left.sh
```

**---EDITS---**

IMPORTANT:
Some info about the origin of AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION can be found [here](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault#how-it-works)

NOTE: **aws sso login** does not appear to set this environment variable, would be curious if someone can clarify if AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION is only present when using aws-vault

Comment: I see the whole answer depends on AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION, but where does that variable comes from?

Comment: `aws sso login` does not appear to set this environment variable.

Comment: If this answer depends on a variable that is only set some of the time or not at all it should be deleted or updated.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `aws configure get` to get the expiry time:

```
AWS_SESSION_EXPIRATION=$(aws configure get ${AWS_PROFILE}.x_security_token_expires)
```

(obviously replace MYPROFILE with your profile name.)

Comment: `aws configure get ${AWS_PROFILE}.x_security_token_expires` was empty for me, even immediately after running `aws sso login`.

Comment: if you use a source_profile then the command changes a little:  

```aws configure get "$(aws configure get ${AWS_PROFILE}.source_profile)".x_security_token_expires```

Comment: that one is also blank for me